# Using Bulma, is there a way to make the hero-body scrollable?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm trying to create a page with a navigation bar and a footer, but I would like them to always stick to the top and bottom of the page, even if the body is long. When the body is long, I would like it to be scrollable (and of course, the navigation and footer would always be visible).

The closest I got to this setup is using `hero` with `is-fullheight` (and its children `hero-head`, `hero-body`, and `hero-footer`), but unfortunately when the body is long, the footer gets pushed outside of view. Any ideas how to make it do what I want, whether it's via Bulma or some CSS tricks?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a "fixed" navbar.

See the documentation about it at https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#fixed-navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar is-fixed-top">
```

You will need to add the bar, then take into account it's height on the html or body element.

```
<html class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
```

For the footer you can just do the same, using the a navbar, but with fixing it to the bottom.